# How to login system with http post connection grails?

Tags: java, http, grails, post, groovy

Hi i am new to grails , i want to create connection to host like(http://ed.yeditepe.edu.tr) with some parameters taken from user(username and password) and then send this parameters with post connection to that host(ed.yeditepe.edu.tr) and make user login to system , any code sample or document for that (by the way user browser must be ie to login system)?

Comment: are you talking about OpenID?

Answer (score 1):

Look into HTTPBuilder - http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/doc/post.html